# changing $scope variables not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that publishes some event based on certain condition. This code doesn't work:

```
 $scope.$on('INTEREST_RECEIVED', function (event, data) {
                if ($scope.user.userID == data.otherUserID) {
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.showAcceptDeclinePanel = true;
                    $scope.showInterestYesNoPanel = false;
                }

        });
```

But this one does:

```
 $scope.$on('INTEREST_RECEIVED', function (event, data) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if ($scope.user.userID == data.otherUserID) {
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.showAcceptDeclinePanel = true;
                    $scope.showInterestYesNoPanel = false;
                }
            }, 50);
        });
```

I have to keep a timeout of 50 ms and then it works perfectly. Am I missing something or why would this happen?

Comment: nothing to do with that.

Comment: When you say it does not work. What do you mean?

Comment: Are you doing something outside Angular's lifecycle? This would justify the reason using the `$timeout` works, as `$timeout` runs your code within a `$apply` (or `$digest`) block, letting angular know about the changes.

Comment: it is hard to say anything when look at this code but my guess is either data or $scope.user is a promise and you should have to wait them to be resolved

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, what doesn't work is already mentioned in the question title "The view is not updated."

Comment: @wickY26: That shouldn't be a problem either since user is already loaded when this event is fired. Infact all conditions are met and variables are updated but the view is not without $timeout.

Comment: Can you post the code that is firing the event?

Comment: how is 'INTEREST_RECEIVED' triggered? if it is triggered by a jQuery or javascript event, then timeout would trigger a digest cycle. If it is triggered by a ng-directive (like ng-click) a timeout should not be needed since angular will automatically call $apply afterwards.

Comment: Since the triger is in the service it is almost for sure incorrect to process the event in $scope.$on. Look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q maybe it it what you are looking for.

Comment: maybe it is happening that your event listener is not able to tell Angular that it has changed something. Try watching over the these two showAcceptDeclinePanel and showInterestYesNoPanel.

Comment: @pixelbits: The event is triggered from a service. The event handler $on is also fired properly but changing the $scope values don't update the views.

Comment: In the Interest Received handler (the code you posted), is $scope a new child scope? and is showAcceptDeclinePanel a variable that is expected to be found in the child scope, or is it expected to be found in the parent scope? The reason I ask is because if scope inheritance is in play, then assigning showAcceptDeclinePanel to the child scope will have the unintended side effect of creating shadow copy of the parent scope variable, and thus breaking the model binding.  If this is the case, try $parent.showAcceptDeclinePanel = true;

Comment: If childscope was in play how would $timeout solve the issue :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling $apply on your scope after the event is triggered:

```
$scope.$on('INTEREST_RECEIVED', function (event, data) {
                if ($scope.user.userID == data.otherUserID) {
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.showAcceptDeclinePanel = true;
                    $scope.showInterestYesNoPanel = false;
                    $scope.$apply()
                }

        });
```

Comment: This does the job. Could you please explain why?

Comment: I assume your INTEREST_RECEIVED event is triggered by jQuery or javascript outside of Angulars lifecycle. As a result you'll need to manually "tell" your environment about changes to you scope. You do this by calling $scope.$apply()